# LInear combinations of infinitely divisible independent random variables are infinitely divisible

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I came across a proposition in the book $\textbf{A modern approach to probability theory}$ by Bert Fristedt and Lawrence Gray which states that linear combinations of infinitely divisible independent random variables are infinitely divisible. The proof is left as an excercise to the reader and I'm wondering if i did it properly.
Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_m$ be independent infinitely divisible random variables. Then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can write $X_i \stackrel{d}{=} X_{i_1} + \dots + X_{i_n}$,  so for every $a_1, \dots, a_m \in \mathbb{R}$ we can write $a_1X_1 + \dots + a_mX_m$ as
\begin{align*}
    a_1X_1 + \dots + a_mX_m &\stackrel{d}{=} \\
                            &\stackrel{d}{=} a_1(X_{1_1} + \dots + X_{1_n}) + \dots + a_m(X_{m_1} + \dots + X_{m_n}) \\
                            &\stackrel{d}{=} \sum_{i=1}^ma_iX_{i_1} + \dots + \sum_{i=1}^ma_iX_{i_n}.
\end{align*}

My main concern is with assuming that $X_{i_j}$ is independent of $X_{k_l}$ for all paris of $i, k \in \{1, ..., m\}$ and $j, l\in \{1, ..., n\}.$

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly choose the entire collection  $(X_{i_j})$ to be independent by going to a 'larger' space.

I would prefer  the following simple argument using characteristic functions:
I will show this for the sum $X_1+X_2+...+X_m$. You can handle linear combinations using  a similar argument (or use the fact that $(a_iX_i)$ are independent and infinitely divisible).

Let $n \in \mathbb N$. If $\phi_i$ is the characteristic function of $X_i$ then there is a characteristic $\phi_{in}$ such that $\phi_{in}^{n}=\phi_i$. Now $(\prod_{i=1}^{m}\phi_{in})^{n}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\phi_{in}^{m}=\prod_{i=1}^{m}\phi_i$ proving that $\prod_{i=1}^{m}\phi_i$ has an $n-$th root for each $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what do you mean by going to a 'larger' space?

Comment: Inifnite divisibility is a property of distributions. You are not required to construct random variables $X_{i_j}$ on the same space  on which $X_i$'s are defined. @VlakecTomaz

Comment: Since you are unfamiliar with construction of independent random variables I strongly recoommend use of characteristic functions to handle questions on infinite divisibility. @VlakecTomaz

Comment: Will do. Thank you.